# Get each line from textarea that contains links with PHP

Tags: php, xml

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702400/get-each-line-from-textarea) solved my problem only until getting each line from textarea. But when I access the link (what contains in each line) with `simplexml_load_file` to get the data, the link started to end with unique codes:

```
foreach ($textAr as $line) {
    echo $line = trim($line)."<br/>"; //I trim it again just to make sure, and the result is the right link.
    echo $xml = simplexml_load_file($line)."<br/>"; //code like %3Cbr/%3E showed up at the end of the link
}
```

And the error is something like:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: simplexml_load_file(*link*%3Cbr/%3E)
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed!

I replace the real link with *link* on the error message.

How to remove the unique codes (%3Cbr/%3E)? I've tried `str_replace("%3Cbr/%3E","",$line)` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a matter of removing `.<br/>`

```
echo $line = trim($line);
```

The `%3Cbr/%3E` represents the `<br/>`

The reason why `str_replace("%3Cbr/%3E","",$line)` doesn't work, is because the line does not contain `%3Cbr/%3E`. It contains `<br/>`. Only if the link tries to open it, it will encode the url, replacing the `<` and `>` signs, which makes it `3Cbr/%3E`.

I'm not sure if you mean to also print all the lines, but if you don't, you can remove the `echo`.

Comment: Oh I see. I meant to see what's inside the `$line` after it trimmed but turns out that the `"<br/>"` I added is the problem. I removed it and add another line `echo $line."<br/>";` Thank you @Ivar