# PHP bind user input for each symbol

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<textarea>
Apple | 1000 | $5  
Banana | 500 | $5
Coconut | 1500 | $5
</textarea>
```

**How To** 
1) Binding each string before the spesific symbol ?

The result must be
**Fruits : Apple, Banana, Coconut**
**Quantity : 1000, 500, 1500**
**Prices : $5, $5, $5**

I have tried this one [Get each line from textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702400/get-each-line-from-textarea) to split each line and it's work, but i don't know how to bind it
**UPDATE**
I've tried to build it by myself and it's work fine

```
<html>
<form method="post">
<textarea name="market"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Split</button>
    </form>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['market'])) {
$text = trim($_POST['market']);
$text = str_replace(' ', '', $text);
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim');

foreach ($textAr as $line) {
    $var = explode('|', $line);
    $fruit = $var[0]; 
    $quantity = $var[1];
    $price = $var[2];

    $data['fruits'][] = $fruit;
}

    echo 'Fruits : '; foreach($data['fruits'] as $rows) { echo $rows.', '; }
}
?>
```

Now i want to ask, how to prevent it from error ?
for example users only input it with

```
<textarea>
Apple | 1000
Banana | 500 \ $5
Coconut | 1500 / $5
</textarea>
```

**Always got error from all of above**

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: @user1309690 i did

Comment: $textAr = explode("\n", $text); should be `$textAr = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);`