# How to get each line of textarea and explode data in it

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, textarea

I'm beginner in php and i tried to realize a soft for my personnal use.

In a teaxarea field name "players", i want to grab each line and use the data in it at my will.

For eg :

My html code is :

```
<form method="post">
<p>
<label for="players">PLAYER :</label>
<br>
<textarea id="players" name="players" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>                    
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="CREATION"></p>
```

If in this teaxtarea i wrote this :

```
NAME FIRSTNAME ID BIRTHDATE
OTHERNAME OTHERFIRSTNAME OTHERID OTHERBIRTHDATA
```

I want to be able to use Name, Firstname, Id, Birthdate and go for the other line and this for each line.

At the beginning I tried this [Get each line from textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702400/get-each-line-from-textarea) but it look like is not working for me : my idea was to use this with a $data=explode(" ", $line); to get an array on what I want.

Currently my result :

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST['players']){
        echo "WORKING";
            $text = trim($_POST['players']);
            $textAr = explode("\n", $text);
            $textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind

            foreach ($textAr as $line) {
                $player=explode("/" , $line);
                echo $player[0]; // processing here.
                echo $player[1]; // processing here.
                echo $player[2]; // processing here.
                echo $player[3]; // processing here.
                echo $player[4]; // processing here.
            } 
    }
?>
```

Comment: `explode(" ", $line);` - but *space* character you are using is *not* a new line?

Comment: This is the second explode : the first one in $testAr should make the job to divide each line. The second one should divide each data of a line where NAME/FIRSTNAME/ID/BDATE

Comment: Yes, it should. Provided such spaces are there and you are splitting the right string

Comment: Currently it's not working, i have a blank page when trying to go on my files.

Comment: if you have a blank page. probably the first condition returns false

Comment: does that mean that the first condition on $_POST is not working ?